# How to fetch field value via REST

Tags: services, polls

I am using Drupal 8. I have installed the Rest module. I need to do polling so I also installed the Poll module. I created two questions with choices in poll and after that I created a view to show polls in that view with Rest Export enabled.

Now there are 3 fields I am showing in my REST export:

- Question
- Choice
- PollID

currently I have two questions and their choices. Here is how its showing in JSON form.

```
     [{"question":"which is best city",
"choice_target_id":"Delhi, Mumbai, Chennai","id":"1"},
    {"question":"Where do you work?",
"choice_target_id":"Flat, Hotel, Factory, Shop","id":"2"}]
```

But the thing is when I access the REST URL in my browser window where I am logged in it shows all the field as.

```
      [
{"question":"which is best city",
    "choice_target_id":"Delhi, Mumbai, Chennai","id":"1"},
    {"question":"Where do you work?",
    "choice_target_id":"Flat, Hotel, Factory, Shop","id":"2"}
]
```

But when I am not login and when I then call the REST URL from Postman 
I get this:

```
[
    {
        "question": "which is best city",
        "choice_target_id": "",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "question": "Where do you work?",
        "choice_target_id": "",
        "id": "2"
    }
]
```

`choice_target_id` is blank. What can be the reason of it?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions? In your views settings page please check the "Authentication" and "Access" values under "PATH SETTINGS" You can also check the permission of the Polls Module.

Comment: Authentication:No authentication is set
Access:None

Comment: this is my setup in path settings

Comment: why there is problem only in choices if it the issue related to permissions